# Perl Can't locate Digest/SHA1.pm in @INC error

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am new to perl, and I am running into trouble.  I am using mojolicious as a frame work I am running into errors while trying to import a module.

```
$self->plugin('SessionStore' => Plack::Session::Store::File->new(dir => $session_dir));
```

The `State.pm` file imports `use Digest::SHA()`;  I am getting an error when the import happens.  Does the `Digest` directory need to be in the same directory as `Plack`
Plack is located in `/usr/share/perl5/` but Digest is located in a different location `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/` do they both have to be in the same location?  I have seen where users are using `use lib 'path to modules'` however this is a perl module i did not create so I do not think that is a good idea.  The actual error states

```
Can't load application from file "/web/applications/perlwebapp/script/startapp":
Can't locate Digest/SHA1.pm in
@INC (you may need to install the Digest::SHA1 module)
(@INC contains: /web/applications/perlwebapp/script/../lib /etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1
/usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26
/usr/share/perl/5.26
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

The weird issue is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/` is in the `@INC` but the module in `/usr/share/perl5` can't see it. If I create a perl script I can `use Digest::SHA();`

my service file.

```
[Service]
Type=forking
User=web
Group=web
#Environment=PERL5LIB=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/
Environment=PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5/
UMask=007
ExecStart=/web/applications/perlwebapp/local/bin/hypnotoad /web/applications/perlwebapp/script/runapp
ExecReload=/web/applications/perlwebapp/local/bin/hypnotoad /web/applications/perlwebapp/script/runapp
ExecStop=/web/applications/perlwebapp/local/bin/hypnotoad --stop /web/applications/perlwebapp/script/runapp
PIDFile=/web/applications/perlwebapp/script/hypnotoad.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed
```

Application code:

```
unless (-d $session_dir){
   make_path($session_dir, {mode => oct("0770")});
 }
$self->plugin('Config');
$self->plugin('RenderFile');
$self->plugin('SessionStore' => Plack::Session::Store::File->new(dir => $session_dir));
validation_checks($self->validator);
```

Comment: How do you run the mojolicious app? What is the content of the `PERL5LIB` environment variable?

Comment: Re "*do they both have to be in the same location?*", No. If you're saying that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/Digest/SHA1.pm` exists, that should be fine. Could it be a permission issue? (Is the user as which the script runs able to acess `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/Digest` and access each of its parents?)

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have a service file that calls my startup file basically `Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('App::DATAPP');` I do not have a `PERL5LIB` variable evironment variable.  Should that be the path to perl5?

Comment: @ikegami I do not think it is a permission issue, but I can double check.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I added `Environment=PERL5LIB=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/` to my service file which contains the `Digest` module.  That did not work.  I then changed `Environment=PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5/`  which is the path that contains `Plack` and `Digest` modules.  I still get the `@INC` error.

Comment: @user3525290 Can you show the complete content of the service file?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I added the service file to the post.  Thanks for all of your help

Comment: Is it the statement: `Plack::Session::Store::File->new(dir => $session_dir)` that fails? Can you show some more of the surrounding code of the app?

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes that is where the error is happening.  I posted more code of the app.

Comment: Can you try add a line just before you load the plugin, the line after `$self->plugin('RenderFile');`. Add this line `require Digest::SHA1;` Does it fail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219330/discussion-between-user3525290-and-hakon-haegland).